# Existence of two disjoint closed sets with zero infimal distance

Tags: general-topology

Are there two closed sets $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with the following properties?

- $A\cap B=\emptyset$
- $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exist $a \in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $\|a-b\| < \epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are. Take $A = \{(x,0): x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and $B = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : xy = 1 \}$. Then points $(n,0) \in A$ and $(n, \frac{1}{n}) \in B$ satisfy $||(n,0) - (n, \frac{1}{n})|| = \frac{1}{n}$, which can be made as small as we like.

So $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists a \in A \exists b \in B: ||a-b|| < \epsilon$.